# Proper way to centralize schema fore databas

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, terraform, schema

We have our infrastructure up in AWS, which includes a database.

Our transfer of data occurs in Python using SQLAlchemy ORM, which we use to mimic the database schema. At this point it's very simple so it's no big deal.

But if the schema changes/grows, then a manual change needs to be done in the code as well each time.

I was wondering: what is the proper way to centralize the schema of the database, so that there is one source of truth for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Glue Schema Registry - this is pretty much what it's made for.